# True/false question about integrable function

Tags: calculus, integration

Prove or give counterexample for this statement:
Let $f$ be an integrable function over $[a,b]$. If $$ \int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx >1$$ then there exists $c$ in $[a,b]$ such that $f(c) > \frac{1}{b-a}$.

Well, it seems obviously true to me. However, I don't know how to prove this. If anyone can guide me it will be great!

Comment: Suppose there were no such $c$. Can you think of a property of the integral operator that then forces $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \leqslant 1$?

Comment: Ok i see..so if is suppose not, it means that for every x in [a,b], (fx)(b-a)<1 . b-a always positive. but now what to do?

Answer (score 1):

U can use the fact that $\int f(x) dx\leq \int g(x) dx$ when $f(x)\leq g(x)$ (on the interval). In particular, set $g(x)=\frac 1{b-a}$ and derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Since $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb R$ is Riemann integrable, we have that $\overline{f}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$, where $\overline{f}$ denotes the mean of $f$ over $[a,b]$. Since $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx>1$ we have that $\overline{f}=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx>\frac{1}{b-a}$. Since the mean of $f$ is *strictly larger than* $\frac{1}{b-a}$, there exists at least one $c\in [a,b]$ such that $f(c)>\frac{1}{b-a}$.

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean#Mean_of_a_function) for more information about the mean of integrable functions.

Comment: You can also use the mean value theorem directly.